# Is it possible to manipulate parameter values in MVC attribute routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can we have a url

```
[Route("Employee/Edit")]
```

pointing to

```
public ActionResult Edit(bool reviewMode=false)
```

while

```
[Route("Employee/Review")]
```

pointing to

```
public ActionResult Edit(bool reviewMode=true)
```

We know we could pass in parameters like

```
[Route("Employee/Edit/{reviewMode}")]
```

for a action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string reviewMode)
{
    if (reviewMode.Equals("review", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    ....
}
```

But our url and the code in Actions will definitely look more elegant if the first two routing patterns can be achieved.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep mode string as your method parameter and check the value of that to set the value of your boolean variable.

```
[Route("Employee/{mode}")]
public ActionResult Edit(string mode = "Edit")
{
    var isReviewModel = String.Equals(mode, "Review",
                                              StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    // to do something based on isReviewModel 
}
```

This will work for `yourSiteName/employee/Review` and `http://localhost:32200/employee/Edit`

When the request url is `employee/Review` , isReviewModel  variable value will be `true` and when the request url is `employee/Edit` the value will be `false`.

Comment: It is a slight improvement. So my understanding is, there is no way we can check the route and pass a boolean `isReviewModel` as a paramter on the action method. Isn't it?